# SQL Best Practice, Is a Small Unchangeable Data Set Worth Creating a New Table for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the scenario where it gets tricky to make a decision based on the fact that the data set values (Content column) will never change. In the first table, and even though the string text will be repeated over and over, is it really still worth it the headache of creating a new table (that is exclusive to this application) and having to depend on joins? If yes or no, why?

*I have been through this scenario many times in the past and always selected to break down tables. However, I am still not entirely convinced so decided to finally ask.*

**Books Table Option 1**:

[image]

**Books Table Option 2**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably want to post this to dba stackexchange but it is a great question

Comment: Usually in an OLTP the second one would be used, but if this is a data warehouse dimension, then option 1 is quite common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a simplicity standpoint, Option 1 is easiest when you first look at it. But I don't think this holds up under the smallest scrutiny.

Option 2 is the right way. Why?

1. This is standard normalization
2. By using a properly sized foreign key, you can minimize the amount of memory taken up by pages of data and keep your indexes smaller. This allows more data caching in memory.
3. What if someone wants Cover to be renamed? Option 2 is clearly superior in large data sets.

As far as the concern about always making the table join... that is what views do. Write a view and never worry about the underlying data structure.